# How to keep a unique data for all the classes/instances using it?

Tags: python

Many had explained the use of static in Python but one point seems not got emphasized. In several other major languages static also means a static datum is a unique(only) copy in the scope. I am coding some astronomical objects that use large VSOP87 data sets. However all the class/derived class or the instances of classes will use only a particular set of the data. In C++/Java/C# using static for those data can easily fulfill the purpose. For instance in C++/C#/Java, the code will almost looks like below:

```
public class Earth
{
.....
static earthVSOP87XYZ[][] = {.....}; // in a very large size
}
```

All the Earth's instances share the only copy of earthVSOP87XYZ and the data are well encapsulated. Is there any way in Python 3 to achieve the same result?

Comment: Please show a code sample that illustrates your problem. Static class variables in Python behave in the same way as in other languages: they exist in the class's scope and are unique regardless of the number of instances.

Comment: What do you mean by "static" in Python?

Comment: Thank u BartoszKP!  I tested what you said as:

class TwoDimList:
    _Val = [ [ i for i in range(6) ] for j in range(6)]
    def __init__(self) :
        for d1 in range(6):
            for d2 in range(6):
                self._Val[d1][d2] = random.randint(0, 9)

    def printVal(self) :
        print(self._Val)

b1.printVal()
b2.printVal()

And both with the same number. It seems that b1 and b2 are using the same instance of _Val.

Answer (score 0):

Great thanks for BartoszKP pointed out that data set defined in Python class behaves like static in other language. I used the code below to verify this:

```
class TwoDimList:
    _Val = [ [ i for i in range(6) ] for j in range(6)]

    def __init__(self) :
        for d1 in range(6):
            for d2 in range(6):
                self._Val[d1][d2] = random.randint(0, 9)

    def printVal(self) :
        print(self._Val)

b1.printVal()
b2.printVal()
```